# Network reply always empty with error : RemoteHostClosedError

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, x509

I have a secured URL working with an x509 certificate and I am supposed to receive a JSON as an answer. My certificate is in pfx format (ca certificate, local certificate, key). I added it on the computer and when launching a request on google chrome and internet explorer with the secured URL I have indeed the JSON as an answer.

My problem is when I try to do the same inside my Qt application I do not have any answer from the same URL. My code :

```
    QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
    config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);

    _manager = std::make_unique<QNetworkAccessManager>();
    auto line = "myurl";
    qInfo() << line;

    QNetworkRequest request((QUrl::fromUserInput(line)));
    request.setSslConfiguration(config);

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(_manager.get(), &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, 
    &QEventLoop::quit, 
    Qt::DirectConnection);

    connect(_manager.get(), &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors, this, 
    &CheckConfController::sslErrors);

    _loginReply = std::unique_ptr<QNetworkReply>(_manager->get(request));

    connect(_loginReply.get(), &QNetworkReply::readyRead,
            this, &CheckConfController::replyFinished);
    connect(_loginReply.get(), &QNetworkReply::finished,
            this, &CheckConfController::_loginReceive);
    loop.exec();
```

The login receive method :

```
void CheckConfController::_loginReceive(){
    qInfo() << "status code : " << _loginReply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    qInfo() << "error : " << _loginReply->error();
    qInfo() << "error string : " << _loginReply->errorString();
    QByteArray b = _loginReply->readAll();
    qInfo() << "byte : " << b;
}
```

The SSL error method :

```
void CheckConfController::sslErrors(QNetworkReply* reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
    QByteArray b = reply->readAll();
    qInfo() << "reply : " << b;

    for(auto element : errors){
        qInfo() << "ssl error : " << element;

    }
}
```

This is mu Outpput :

```
status code: QVariant(Invalid)
error: QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError
err string: "Connection Closed"
byte : ""
```

SSL error is never called.

I switched my URL *line* to *https://www.google.com* and it works fine. I also tried with other urls and i receive my json correctly.

This is my configuration:

```
Qt version: 5.12.11
compiler: MSVC 2017 64 bits
Computer running the application: Windows 7
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Another thing is that, I wonder why you would add certificate manually. Qt will automatically use system's certificate(s).

Comment: Hello @Top-Master. Thanks for replying. At the end i gave my Qt version : 5.12.11 along with other informations. About the certificate i noticed i didnt have to add it manually since its already added on the computer itself. And i already used other urls to test my code and it worked.

Comment: I think you mean, you no longer add certificate manually (hence your question's code needs edit), and that the code works for other HTTP`S` URLs. So, maybe your Site's certificate is invalid (maybe expired, or not supported).

Comment: @Top-Master the certificate is valid because i can use it with google chrome and internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

### Update

After comments below this answer, I noticed the server that OP is trying to reach has certificate limitations, hence defaulting to system certificates is not an option, because we can't be sure which certificate is used.

Now that we know that, I suggest ensuring that your certificate is somehow preferred, for example try:

```
QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

I mean, at end of OP's original code:

```
QSslKey key;
QSslCertificate certificate;
QList<QSslCertificate> certChain;

bool imported = QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(&pfxFile, &key, &certificate, &certChain, "mypassphrase");
qInfo() << "imported : " << imported;


QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setCaCertificates(certChain);
config.setLocalCertificate(certificate);
config.setPrivateKey(key);
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);
```

### Old answer

As comments said:

- OP no longer adds certificate manually (and adds it to system),
- Also, OP's code works for other `HTTPS` URLs.
- Last but not least, OP's Site has valid certificate, and logs just mention closed connection.

Counting all together, this does not seem to have anything to do with Qt. OP's site simply rejects any `JSON` request.

> Maybe try setting auth header (or, do whatever else the site's requirements are).
>
> I usually use Postman App (to test sites' API and routes).

Comment: Hello. I tried to figure it out on my side and i do not find any solution. I had a debug session with a developer of the server i am trying to reach. They receive my request but it is automatically rejected with a 401 status code on their side. No ssl errors on either side. Do you have any suggestion ? Thank you.

Comment: @mhzar Maybe you asked the wrong questions (from said server's developer); Instead of asking about SSL and/or Qt, you should simply ask how to authenticate to their server, and once that works, ask how or where to pass the token (if required).

Comment: @mhzar Actually, if the server is a well known service, like Stripe, I recommend asking separate question, I mean, ask about the service usage (not Qt and/or SSL).

Comment: Thanks for replying. To authenticate to the server i have to use the certificate i am using on my code. I added it on the computer and my request works fine on google chrome and internet explorer. Now i know my certificate is used by Qt for the request. I dont understand what is the difference between Qt and chrome/Inernet Explorer considering the certificate is always used. Maybe i should ask a new question for this.

Comment: @mhzar Okay; just when you say Chrome, I hope you mean some JSON-request-making extension (like Postman), because there are huge differences between JSON vs opening some address.

Comment: I am not using Postman. I open my url on google chrome and the page shows me a JSON if i have a valid certitifcate. On internet explorer it does not open the page but the json is downloaded as a file. I have noticed the first time i open chrome, it makes me choose the certificate manually.

Comment: @mhzar I see; seems the server always returns JSON. And certificate is limited to a specific one. Well, these changes my answer a lot (see above update).

Comment: i saw your updated answer and despite not having to add the certificate manually i still kept that part in my code. I also already tried to add my config with setDefaultConfiguration and it did not work. The best thing to do now is to work alongside a developper on server side to figure out what the problem is. I really want to thank you for your time and your help. I really appreciated it.